# JSONP - Callback was not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, get, jsonp

I created a jsonp ajax call for getting data via cross domain.
The thing right now is - I successfully manipulated it to send data over a webserver.

But it fails receiving data in a get call. When I have look in the debugger I see that the network tab receives the file and within there is the data. But I still get an error message.

The url gets a parameter with the jquery callback key. My webservices uses that key and adds it again in the response header. (which I also see in the debugger). I also receive a `OK` `200` status code in the network tab that the data is received...

The question now is why the ajax call doesn't jump into the success function but shows me everytime the error that the callback isn't called.

What do I do wrong?

The code looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: getServicePath,
        dataType: 'jsonp',  
        username: "abc",
        password: "123",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(results) {
                 alert(results);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }
```

Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: it looks like the remote resource you are trying to use is not supporting jsonp.... just using jsonp in the client side is not sufficient... it needs to be supported by the server also

Comment: But I am setting the original callback in the response header from the remote resouce. like:
Response Headers: callback:jQuery171011685512703843415_1415089316044

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The webservice is an SAP ABAP webservice. The problem was that I didn't include the following line of code to support jsonp correctly.

CONCATENATE _callback
               '('
               _json_string
               ')'
          INTO _json_string.